# Listar Archivos Android Studio(Java)

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de listar archivos de directorios pero me pace como si los directorios estuvieran vacios :

```
     File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = dir.getAbsolutePath();

    File carpeta = new File(path);
    String[] listado = carpeta.list();
    if (listado == null || listado.length == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual");
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i=0; i< listado.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(listado[i]);
        }
    }
```

He comprobado los directorios y si tienen archivos , es memoria interna y tambien tiene los permisos la app.
Lo consegui dando los permisos de Almacenamiento de manera manual, hay forma de automatizarlo ?

Comment: Hola, revisaste la definición del permiso? no es solo requerirlo manualmente debe ser declararlo y requerirlo manualmente, en este caso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu còdigo debe funcionar, pero recuerda que aunque requieras permisos para lectura/escritura (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) es muy importante que el permiso se encuentre tambièn definido dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```